# Face a problem convert emoji to unicode in string

Tags: python, python-unicode

I'm trying to display emoji with unicode in xml file. But facing a problem now. If I want to convert emoji to unicode which emoji is contained in a string such as below.

"Fox Business News is fascinated with #Bitcoin However, it still feels like we are early "
[This picture is how the xml file looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgbDc.png)

[This picture is what I want emoji shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWA7G.png)

How can I convert emoji to unicode so that the string will show like "Fox Business News is fascinated with #Bitcoin However, it still feels like we are early &#XXXXXX"?

What I'm trying to do is there are many sentences which might contain emoji or not contain emoji. I need to find out which of them contain emoji and convert emoji to unicode so that it can be displayed with unicode like the picture above.

I'm doing regular expression related question. Therefore other packages except re cannot be imported.

Appreciated if anyone can help solve this question!

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me what you want to do. You say "... so that the string will show like..." but that will depend on what program or method you use to show it. If you replace the `` with `&amp;#129321;` (I think), would that be ok for you?

Comment: Is this what you're asking for: `text.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode()` -> `'Fox Business News is fascinated with #Bitcoin However, it still feels like we are early &#129321;'`?

Comment: I have added more information, sorry for not clarifying clearly.

Comment: @QZhong Did you try my suggestion? It seems to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @ekhumoro oh. It works! Appreciate for that! I was stucked here for long time